# Using CSS to place an object outside of its parent that contains dynamic text length

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I'm hoping this isn't a stupid question, but I've been messing around with this longer than necessary and decided to reach out for answers.

I'm trying to achieve the following, centred on a page:

[ [dynamically changing text] [img] [other text] ]

The length of the text on the left shouldn't affect the centred nature of the whole block.

**The image should be at the centre of the screen regardless of the text surrounding it.**

I've tried to use a negative translate on the left text, which achieves the affect, but doesn't scale when the text string changes length.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid green;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}

.long-text {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.image-block {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translatex(-100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="long-text">Longer text goes in here</span>
  <div class="image-block">
    <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/30x30" alt="" />  
    <span>Shorter text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This still needs work, but is this what you're going for? https://jsfiddle.net/96w0zy7b/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making blocks on the left and on the right from the image equal width can be easily achieved with Flexbox, by setting them `flex:1`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: flex;
}
.wrapper > span {
   flex: 1;
}

.long-text {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  text-align: right;
}

.image-block {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="long-text">Longer text goes in here</span>
  <div class="image-block">
    <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/30x30" alt="" /> 
  </div>
  <span>Shorter text</span>
</div>
```

Is it what you looked for?

Comment: This is the best answer providing the easiest solution and will not cause issues with other styles inside the children...

Answer (score 0):

like this? you need `.wrapper` to be span

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrap {
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

.long-text {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  display: inline-block;
}

.image-block {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inherit;
  /*transform: translatex(-100%);*/
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <span class="wrapper">
  <span class="long-text">Longer text goes in here</span>
  <div class="image-block">
    <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/30x30" alt="" />
    <span>Shorter text</span>
  </div>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, I realised I missed a key line from my problem, which I've added to the edit:

The image should be at the centre of the screen regardless of the text surrounding it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use blow code.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrap {
  text-align: center;
  width:100%
}

.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

.long-text {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  width:49%;
}

.image-block {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
  width:50%;
  vertical-align: top;
  /*transform: translatex(-100%);*/
}
.image-block img {
float: left;
}
.image-block divv {
padding-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <span class="wrapper">
  <span class="long-text">Longer text goes in here sdffdssdfsdssdf Longer text goes in here sdffdssdfsdssdf Longer text goes in here sdffdssdfsdssdf Longer text goes in here sdffdssdfsdssdf</span>
  <div class="image-block">
    <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/30x30" alt="" />
    <div>Shorter text</div>
  </div>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks about right, but do you think it can be done without float?

Comment: Yes it's possible then you need to remove float:left and just need to add display:inline-block; please check my update answer.